# iOS4 controller performance

Tags: ios4

I am creating an game application for iPhone that uses two controllers. One for the main view which basically is som buttons to start the game.

The game is a game that renders in drawRect and is therefore quite performance critical. My question is:
Are there any performance cons to use

```
[self presentModalViewController:tmpControler animated:NO];
```

When switching from the main view controller to the "game controller"?
Or should I use another way?